# how to get mutual friends between two friends using graph api v2.2 android sdk

Tags: android

I want to get the mutual friends between two friends using Graph Api in android. I am using  Graph api for mutual friends but it is giving only those friends who are using my applications not mutual friends.

Comment: Guys is there anyone who can help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do what you want. The only thing the mutual_friends edge will return are mutual friends that are already using your app, and a count of all the mutual friends the users share (which include the users that don't use your app)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user.context/mutual_friends

There is no way to return ALL mutual friends between 2 users. Not since v2.0 anyways